# Can't access date field in fieldset

Tags: rules, entities

I am using rules and I'm trying to retrieve a field inside a field collection for my scheduled component.

I have the conditions "Entity has field" and have selected my field, but I still can't access it in the data selection for my component.

I am using Drupal 7.52, Rules 7-2.9, & Rules Scheduler 7-2.9.

**Update** I have discovered that I can access other fields in the fieldset, but I just can't access the date fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, solved it.

I wasn't suppose to add the action under Components, rather I was suppose to add the action under Rules Scheduler > Schedule component evaluation.